# MySql Data truncated for column 'advance' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, swing, double

In my project I used txtAdvance 's key event.

```
    double gtotal = Double.parseDouble(txtGtotal.getText());
    double ad = Double.parseDouble(txtAdvance.getText());
    double due = gtotal - ad;
    txtDue.setText(String.valueOf(due));
```

And after last line run,  I add a save button to save those data. Given below is that query.

```
    public void saveInvoice(JTextField txtgtotal, JTextField txtAdvance, JTextField txtDue, JTextField txtInID) {

    try {
        db.putData("INSERT INTO indetails(inid, gtotal, advance, due) VALUES( '" + txtInID.getText() + "' ,'" + txtgtotal.getText() + "' , '" + txtAdvance.getText() + " ' " + " , '" + txtDue.getText() + "') ");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, txtAdvance.getText());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invoice details saved");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + " first " + e);
    }
}
```

I'm having MySql Data truncated for column 'advance' at row 1 . advance's data type is Double. But I can't find a way to put length. 
(As an example
 *Column Name* : iid, Data type : Int(18) {Primary key} 
 *Column Name* : inid, Data type : Int(18) 
 *Column Name* : gtotal, Data type : Double 
 *Column Name* : advance, Data type : Double 
 *Column Name* : due, Data type : Double 
)

I'm using MySQL query browser . Question is when I'm adding 0 value to txtAdvance I'm having this error.

Comment: I'm using JDBC connection.

Comment: What does `putData` method? Why don't you use `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: Your PreparedStatement should look:`"INSERT INTO indetails(inid, gtotal, advance, due) VALUES(?,?,?,?)` and you should use `setDouble(2, ad)` for setting `advance` column.

Comment: @aged I think my query is right as you say. I'm sorry I couldn't find setting advance cloumn in mysql query browser. Can you please explane that to me little bit. I'll be really greatful to you.

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you are trying to save have decimal points then change the **datatype** for **advance** as **double** with length **10,3** where **10** denotes number of digits and **3** denotes the number of decimal digits.

Use this query,

```
db.putData("INSERT INTO indetails(inid, gtotal, advance, due) VALUES(" + txtInID.getText() + "," + txtgtotal.getText() + "," + txtAdvance.getText() + "," + txtDue.getText()+")");
```

Comment: @Dilini Only for all **character/varchar/date/timestamp** datatype we must use **single quotes** and for **numbers** we don't need to use anything

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your query by hand, you should use db driver for it:

> PreparedStatement putData  = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO indetails(inid, gtotal, advance, due) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

```
double gtotal = Double.parseDouble(txtGtotal.getText());
double ad = Double.parseDouble(txtAdvance.getText());
double due = gtotal - ad;

putData.setInt(1, inid);
putData.setDouble(2, gtotal);
putData.setDouble(3, ad);
putData.setDouble(4, due);

try {
    putData.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, txtAdvance.getText());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invoice details saved");
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + " first " + e);
}
```

Comment: @aged but putData.setInt(1, inid); is not recognized as a method. It is only working db.putData(sql query); What should I do?

Comment: In the code above `putData` is variable of type `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, so `putData.setInt(1, inid);` must work.